# Error while importing python o/p to ms access

Tags: python, database, error-handling, pyodbc, ms-access-2013

code I used to establish connection between python code and ms-access

```
 import pyodbc
    conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=D:\LnT_project\Project.accdb;')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("Insert into dbtable (File_name, File_size) values(abc, 2)")
    conn.commit()
```

I am getting this error:

pyodbc.Error: ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 2. (-3010) (SQLExecDirectW)')

Answer (score 0):

Try with quotes to mark as a text value:

```
cursor.execute("Insert into dbtable (File_name, File_size) values('abc', 2)")
```

Comment: HEY, thanks what should we do for expected 2?

Comment: That, I guess, is a number value, so it is OK.

Comment: thanks for your time but the problem I am facing now is this current error : pyodbc.Error: ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 2. (-3010) (SQLExecDirectW)'), what should I do for this? coz my output is not being exported in ms access, I have changed 'abc' and 's' to the variable folder and s which I need to export

Comment: That error typically indicates missing or misspelled table or field names. So, double-check these.